# How do I programmatically click on a div in a web browser?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been trying for a few days now and still have had no success in programmatically clicking on this div.  All of the other input fields and buttons are working fine using InvokeMember("click") and RaiseEvent("onclick"), but I am unable to click on the following div:

```
<div class="pump request"> onclick="$(this).push('kjhzsd94vibjktj584ed01', null, event)" </div>
```

This div is repeated several times on a page, but I just want to click on the first occurrence.

This is what I have done so far:

```
 HtmlElementCollection c1 = wbc1.document.GetElementsByTagName("div");

 foreach (HtmlElement e2 in c1)
 {
    if (e2.GetAttribute("class").Contains("pump request"))//also this condition is not returning true
       {
          e2.RaiseEvent("onclick");              
       }
 }
```

---

@bleepzter

what if "somecontrol" is a class of the div instead of div's id?

since in my case i have div class "pump request" so (if i write "pump request" as somecontrol in above example) it return me Null in someDiv

```
<div class="pump request"> onclick="$(this).push('kjhzsd94vibjktj584ed01', null, event)" </div>
```

@Cameron

yep i did entered the break; but the problem is the if condition never returns true so

```
    HtmlElementCollection c1 = wbc1.document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
    foreach (HtmlElement e2 in c1)
 {
    if (e2.GetAttribute("class").Contains("pump request"))//--> This condition is not returning true
       {
          e2.RaiseEvent("onclick"); 
          break;              
       }
 }
```

@Ilya Kogan

yea i just did a watch on e2.GetAttribute("class") and the weird thing happened that being reading the actual div (which i want to click) the value of class was empty :-o

Comment: Did you try to debug and see what e2.GetAttribute("class") **does** return?

Comment: There's no guarantee the class attribute being read out of the DOM contains the classes in exactly the same order as they were written in the source. Also, if you just want the first element, you should probably have a `break;` statement at the end of your `if`

Answer (score 4):

try this one

```
if (e2.GetAttribute("className").Contains("pump request"))
{
    e2.InvokeMember("Click");              
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this piece of code by using a web browser control.

```
 // browser is the web browser control
 HtmlElementCollection col = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
            foreach (HtmlElement helemnt in col)
            {
                if (helemnt.InnerText !=null && helemnt.InnerText=="something") 
                {

                    helemnt.InvokeMember("Click");

                       break; // break the loop

                }



            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Here is an example which assumes your browser control is called `browser`, and the div you are looking for is called `somecontrol` (i.e. the id of the div is `somecontrol`):

```
HtmlElement someDiv = browser.Document.All["somecontrol"];
object someDivElement = someDiv.DomElement;

MethodInfo clickMethod = someDivElement.GetType().GetMethod("click");
clickMethod.Invoke(someDivElement, null);
```

All this is possible via reflection.